# If a company has been selling your patented invention on the market

Tags: patent-infringement

If the patent has been granted, what are your next steps. Assuming that you are successful in those next steps, what will you be able to get from the company? Will you be able to get 100% of profits that the company made from selling your invention?

Answer (score 0):

This would be better posted on the [Law SE site](https://law.stackexchange.com). That said, I think the process is you contact a lawyer and that lawyer advises you. How the courts rule with respect to a law suit, I assume, is based on the merits of the specific case. So you might get all their profits. You might get less and if the infringement is especially bad more.

Comment: This answer includes relevant information there, for e.g.: https://law.stackexchange.com/a/84573/36359